# Setting onSubmit in React.js

Tags: javascript, forms, form-submit, reactjs, onsubmit

On submission of a form, I'm trying to `doSomething()` instead of the default post behaviour.

Apparently in React, [onSubmit is a supported event for forms.](http://facebook.github.io/react/docs/events.html#form-events) However, when I try the following code:

```
var OnSubmitTest = React.createClass({
    render: function() {
        doSomething = function(){
           alert('it works!');
        }

        return <form onSubmit={doSomething}>
        <button>Click me</button>
        </form>;
    }
});
```

The method `doSomething()` is run, but thereafter, the default post behaviour is still carried out.

You can test this in my [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ayda5w9m/).

My question: How do I prevent the default post behaviour?

Answer (score 141, accepted):

In your `doSomething()` function, pass in the event `e` and use `e.preventDefault()`.

```
doSomething = function (e) {
    alert('it works!');
    e.preventDefault();
}
```

Comment: As of v0.13, returning false from event handlers will be ignored, so you'll have to use e.preventDefault() or e.stopPropagation()

Comment: I think you mean the former

Comment: @SharkLasers That comment was made on a edit of this post that is no longer available.

Comment: Fair enough, you should probably delete comments when they are no longer relevant though.

Answer (score 56):

I'd also suggest moving the event handler outside render.

```
var OnSubmitTest = React.createClass({

  submit: function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    alert('it works!');
  }

  render: function() {
    return (
      <form onSubmit={this.submit}>
        <button>Click me</button>
      </form>
    );
  }
});
```

Comment: This is proper way of using form in component :)

Answer (score 26):

```
<form onSubmit={(e) => {this.doSomething(); e.preventDefault();}}></form>
```

it work fine for me

Answer (score 6):

You can pass the event as argument to the function and then prevent the default behaviour.

```
var OnSubmitTest = React.createClass({
        render: function() {
        doSomething = function(event){
           event.preventDefault();
           alert('it works!');
        }

        return <form onSubmit={this.doSomething}>
        <button>Click me</button>
        </form>;
    }
});
```

Comment: In my case, it works with and without `this`: `{this.doSomething}` or `{doSomething}` is fine because `doSomething` is withing the `render()`.