# How to call two functions onSubmit in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

I am trying to call two functions on the same onSubmit event in React. My approach is two wrap the two functions in a parent function, and call the parent function, as follows:

```
  Submit() { 
function1 () {}; 
function 2 () {}; 
}
```

Is there any glaring error in the way that I am going about this? I am getting a syntax error so I imagine it is a small error I am overlooking. Does the syntax above make sense?

Comment: If it’s not only the space between function and 2, can we have the complete class code?

Comment: Here is an answer which was already given to the similar question. https://stackoverflow.com/a/26069299/4510870

Answer (score 2):

you code dont look right...
If you talking about calling 2 functions here is how:

```
   submit(){
//calling functions
this.function1();
this.function2();
}
//declaring functions
function1(){}
function2(){}
```

Comment: To add to this, if this is hooked on an onSubmit, one should pass the event as a parameter into submit() and call preventDefault() on the event

Answer (score 0):

There are various to achieve the above task and one among them is the one you mentioned.

- Method :
  You have syntax error in line 3 as there is space b/w `function` and `2`.
  `submit(){
    func1();
    func2();
  }`
  Also you'll find this link useful :
  [Setting onSubmit in React.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28479239/setting-onsubmit-in-react-js#28479430)