# How to create array from state value and setstate after removing duplicates in reactjs

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, state, setstate

React newbie, This is very basic form submit but what I am trying to do here is create array from the value received from the input then and setState with array but before setState also remove any duplicates in the array.

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';

class Chase extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      value: ''
    };
  }
  handleSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
// Should I create array in the handlesubmit ?
  };

  handleChange = (e) => {
      e.preventDefault()
      let newspoo = e.target.value
      let createArr= newspoo.split(' ')
      let newVal = Array.from(new Set(createArr))
       this.setState({ newVal}, () =>{
        console.log(newVal)
    });
// this works in console but on display I cannot see any values in the UI
  };

  render() {

    const {value} = this.state
    return (
      <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
       <div>
       <label>
          Name:
          <input
            type='text'
            value={this.state.value}
            onChange={this.handleChange}
          />
        </label>
        <input type='submit' value='Submit' />
       </div>
       <div>
       <label>
            Output : 
         {/* I am trying to print the new array here after submitting the form */}
        </label>
        <p>{value}</p>
       </div>
      </form>
    );
  }
}

export default Chase;
```

Answer (score 1):

## Issue

You don't update your state with the correct key `value`, instead you are adding a new state variable `this.state.newVal`.

## Solution

```
handleChange = (e) => {
  e.preventDefault()
  let newspoo = e.target.value
  let createArr= newspoo.split(' ')
  let newVal = Array.from(new Set(createArr))
  this.setState(
    { value: newVal }, // <-- use correct state key
    () => {
      console.log(newVal)
    },
  );
};
```

Comment: Thanks @Drew it worked, also can you explain me does handleSubmit should hold the state or its only to have the prevent default method?

Comment: @Zeba Sorry, I don't quite understand what you are asking. We use `event.preventDefault()` on a `form` element's `onSubmit` event so any default form actions are not taken, primarily the navigation/page reload that occurs. Can you clarify what you are asking for me?

Comment: My apologize for confusing @Drew, I meant this question which I found the answer here https://stackoverflow.com/q/28479239/11737583