# Why is my onSubmit not working in PrimeReact Dialog?

Tags: reactjs, dialog, onsubmit, primereact

My code is no longer submitting data when onSubmit is pushed even though it was when I was using a  and  tag:

```
<Modal><Form onSubmit={ saveProject }></Form></Modal>
```

The only thing different now is I substituted Modal for  as I am using PrimeReact and deleted the  tag. Now it's no longer submitting data.
Can anyone tell me why it is no longer submitting the data to the backend?

/Projects.js

```js
    import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
    import { Column } from "primereact/column";
    import { DataTable } from "primereact/datatable";
    import { Button } from "primereact/button";
    // import { Modal, ModalFooter, ModalHeader } from "react-bootstrap";
    import { InputText } from "primereact/inputtext";
    import { InputTextarea } from "primereact/inputtextarea";
    // import { InputNumber } from "primereact/inputnumber";
    import { Dropdown } from "primereact/dropdown";
    import { Dialog } from "primereact/dialog";
    
    import axios from "axios";
    
    const Projectz = () => {
        const [ticket_title, setTicketTitle] = useState("");
        const [ticket_description, setTicketDescription] = useState("");
        // const [time_takes, setTimeTakes] = useState("");
        const [type_menu, setTypeMenu] = useState("");
        const [priority_menu, setPriorityMenu] = useState("");
        const [status_menu, setStatusMenu] = useState("");
    
        const [projects, setProjects] = useState([]);
    
        //part of modal
        const [displayResponsive, setDisplayResponsive] = useState(false);
        // const [position, setPosition] = useState("center");
    
        useEffect(() => {
            getProjects();
        }, []);
    
        const getProjects = async () => {
            const response = await axios.get("http://localhost:5002/ticket_table");
            setProjects(response.data);
        };
    
        const saveProject = async (e) => {
            e.preventDefault();
            await axios.post("http://localhost:5002/ticket_table", {
                ticket_title: ticket_title,
                ticket_description: ticket_description,
                // time_takes: time_takes,
                type_menu: type_menu,
                priority_menu: priority_menu,
                status_menu: status_menu,
            });
        };
    
        const dropdownValues1 = [{ value: "Issue" }, { value: "Bug" }, { value: "Error" }, { value: "Other" }];
    
        const dropdownValues2 = [{ value: "Low" }, { value: "Medium" }, { value: "High" }, { value: "Immediate" }];
    
        const dropdownValues3 = [{ value: "New" }, { value: "Open" }, { value: "In Progress" }, { value: "Resolved" }, { value: "Additional Info Required" }];
    
        const dialogFuncMap = {
            displayResponsive: setDisplayResponsive,
        };
    
        const onClick = (name, position) => {
            dialogFuncMap[`${name}`](true);
        };
    
        const onHide = (name) => {
            dialogFuncMap[`${name}`](false);
        };
    
        const renderFooter = (name) => {
            return (
                <div>
                    <Button label="Submit" className="p-button-rounded p-button-success mr-2 mb-2 success" />
                </div>
            );
        };
    
        // const [show, setShow] = useState(false);
        // const handleClose = () => setShow(false);
        // const handleShow = () => setShow(true);
        return (
            <>
                <div className="grid table-demo">
                    <div className="col-12">
                        <div className="card">
                            <h5>Tickets</h5>
    
                            <div>
                                {/* <Button label="New Ticket" className="p-button-rounded mr-2 mb-2 npbutton" onClick={handleShow} /> */}
                                <Button className="p-button-rounded mr-2 mb-2 npbutton" label="New Ticket" onClick={() => onClick("displayResponsive")} />
                            </div>
                            <Dialog className="dialogModal" header="Create Ticket" visible={displayResponsive} onHide={() => onHide("displayResponsive")} breakpoints={{ "960px": "75vw" }} style={{ width: "30vw" }} footer={renderFooter("displayResponsive")}>
                                <form onSubmit={saveProject}>
                                    <h5>Ticket Name</h5>
                                    <InputText value={ticket_title} onChange={(e) => setTicketTitle(e.target.value)} type="text" placeholder="Enter ticket name"></InputText>
                                    <h5>Ticket Description</h5>
                                    <InputTextarea value={ticket_description} onChange={(e) => setTicketDescription(e.target.value)} type="text" placeholder="Enter ticket description" autoResize rows="3" cols="30" />
                                    {/* <h5>Time Estimate (Hours)</h5> */}
                                    {/* <InputNumber value={time_takes} onValueChange={(e) => setTimeTakes(e.value)} showButtons mode="decimal"></InputNumber> */}
                                    <h5>Type</h5>
                                    <Dropdown value={type_menu} onChange={(e) => setTypeMenu(e.value)} options={dropdownValues1} optionLabel="value" placeholder="Select" />
                                    <h5>Priority</h5>
                                    <Dropdown value={priority_menu} onChange={(e) => setPriorityMenu(e.value)} options={dropdownValues2} optionLabel="value" placeholder="Select" />
                                    <h5>Status</h5>
                                    <Dropdown value={status_menu} onChange={(e) => setStatusMenu(e.value)} options={dropdownValues3} optionLabel="value" placeholder="Select" />
                                </form>
                            </Dialog>
                            <div>
                                <DataTable
                                    // sortMode="single" sortField="representative.name"
    
                                    sortOrder={1}
                                    scrollable
                                    scrollHeight="400px"
                                    responsiveLayout="scroll"
                                >
                                    <Column field="ticket_title" header="Ticket Title" style={{ minWidth: "200px" }}></Column>
                                    <Column field="description" header="Description" style={{ minWidth: "350px" }}></Column>
                                    <Column field="status" header="Status" style={{ minWidth: "200" }}></Column>
                                    <Column field="createdAt" header="Date" style={{ minWidth: "200px" }}></Column>
                                </DataTable>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
    
                <div className="grid table-demo">
                    <div className="col-12">
                        <div className="card">
                            <h5>Ticket Info</h5>
                            <div>
                                <DataTable
                                // value={projects}
                                // sortMode="single" sortField="representative.name"
                                // sortOrder={1}
                                // scrollable
                                // scrollHeight="400px"
                                // responsiveLayout="scroll"
                                >
                                    {projects.map((project, index) => (
                                        <tr key={project.id}>
                                            <td>{index + 1}</td>
                                            <td>{project.ticket_title}</td>
                                            <td>{project.ticket_description}</td>
                                            {/* <td>{ticket.time_takes}</td> */}
                                            <td>{project.type_menu}</td>
                                            <td>{project.priority_menu}</td>
                                            <td>{project.status_menu}</td>
                                        </tr>
                                    ))}
                                </DataTable>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </>
        );
    };
    
    export default React.memo(Projectz);
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28479239/setting-onsubmit-in-react-js Look at this, its already answered

Comment: @Tirth in what way? Their submit function already calls `preventDefault`.

Comment: @Tirth saveProject already calls e.preventDefault() so that answer doesn't really help me so much but I appreciate your efforts to help!

Comment: I added back the <form> tag as onSubmit is a prop for a form but it's still not working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because the Dialog renders `renderFooter` outside of your `<form>`. I ran into the same issue.

You can fix it instead of using the footer just rendering your button to look like its in the footer.

```xml
<Dialog className="dialogModal" header="Create Ticket" visible={displayResponsive} onHide={() => onHide("displayResponsive")} breakpoints={{ "960px": "75vw" }} style={{ width: "30vw" }}>
    <form onSubmit={saveProject}>
          ....
          <div className="p-dialog-footer pb-0">
              <Button label="Submit" type="submit" className="p-button-rounded p-button-success mr-2 mb-2" />
          </div>
    </form>
</Dialog>
```