# can't call function on submitting react form

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, forms, web-frontend

I've created a react form and I cant call the function handleSubmit on submitting the form, everything looks fine to me but I'm sure there's a basic mistake that I'm making. Here's the code

```
import React from "react";
import {useState} from "react";
import Button from "./Button";
function Form(){
    const [name, setName] = useState("");
    const [email, setEmail] = useState("");
    const [subject, setSubject] = useState("");
    const [message, setMessage] = useState("");

    function handleSubmit(event){
        console.log("Worker");
        if(name===""||email===""||subject===""||message===""){
            event.preventDefault()
        }else{
             fetch("http://localhost:3000/formSubmit", {
                method: 'POST',
                headers: {
                    'Accept': 'application/json',
                    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
             },
                body: JSON.stringify({ 
                name: name,
                email:email,
                subject:subject,
                message:message
            })
        })
    }
}

return(
    <div id="contact" className="fade-bottom ">
        <div id="form">
            <form id="form-internal" onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
                <h3 id="form-head">Contact Me!</h3>
                <input className="input-text" type="text" min={3} max={50} size={16} placeholder="Name"    value={name} onChange={(e) => setName(e.target.value)} />
                <input className="input-text" type="text" min={8} max={30} size={16} placeholder="Email" value={email} onChange={(e) => setEmail(e.target.value)} />
                <input className="input-text" type="text" min={1} max={30} size={16} placeholder="Subject" value={subject} onChange={(e) => setSubject(e.target.value)} />              
                <textarea id="message" min={1} max={300} size={34} type="text" placeholder="Message" value={message} onChange={(e) => setMessage(e.target.value)} />                   
                <input type="submit" id="submit-form" placeholder="Submit"/>
            </form>
        </div>
        </div>
     );
  }
export default Form;
```

"Worker" isnt being printed.

I have tried using other similar approaches like making it

const handleSubmit = (event)=>{.....}

and used async and even without it, can't get it to work

Comment: try calling the function like this onSubmit={(e)=>handleSubmit(e)}

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

you should call `event.preventDefault()` first, it basically default action that belongs to the event will not occur. Every time handleSubmit is called your app is rerendered, so to avoid this, you need to call it at first
refer here https://stackoverflow.com/a/28480839/10220184

```js
function handleSubmit(event){

        event.preventDefault() // here
        console.log("Worker");

        if(name===""||email===""||subject===""||message===""){
            alert('Enter all values') // some action you wanted
        }else{
             fetch("http://localhost:3000/formSubmit", {
                method: 'POST',
                headers: {
                    'Accept': 'application/json',
                    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
             },
                body: JSON.stringify({ 
                name: name,
                email:email,
                subject:subject,
                message:message
            })
        })
    }
```

Comment: Tried this and now page isnt reloading, but "Worker" is still not being printed in the console due to which I suspect my backend call to localhost:3000 is not taking place at all. Can you maybe suggest me a different approach for making this backend call that takes place on submitting the form.

Answer (score 0):

Try `onSubmit={(event) => handleSubmit(event)}` and use `FormData` To submit

```
import React from "react";
import {useState} from "react";
import Button from "./Button";
function Form(){
    const [name, setName] = useState("");
    const [email, setEmail] = useState("");
    const [subject, setSubject] = useState("");
    const [message, setMessage] = useState("");

    function handleSubmit(event){
        event.preventDefault()
        console.log("Worker");
        if(name===""||email===""||subject===""||message===""){
            console.log("Fill All Fields")
        } else{
            let formData = new FormData();
            formData.append('name', name);
            formData.append('email', email);
            formData.append('subject', subject);
            formData.append('message', message);

            fetch("http://localhost:3000/formSubmit", {
                method: 'POST',
                headers: {
                    'Accept': 'application/json',
                    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                },
                body: formData,
            })
        }
    }

return(
    <div id="contact" className="fade-bottom ">
        <div id="form">
            <form id="form-internal" onSubmit={(event) => handleSubmit(event)}>
                <h3 id="form-head">Contact Me!</h3>
                <input className="input-text" type="text" min={3} max={50} size={16} placeholder="Name" required value={name} onChange={(e) => setName(e.target.value)} />
                <input className="input-text" type="text" min={8} max={30} size={16} placeholder="Email" required value={email} onChange={(e) => setEmail(e.target.value)} />
                <input className="input-text" type="text" min={1} max={30} size={16} placeholder="Subject" required value={subject} onChange={(e) => setSubject(e.target.value)} />              
                <textarea id="message" min={1} max={300} size={34} type="text" placeholder="Message" required value={message} onChange={(e) => setMessage(e.target.value)} />                   
                <input type="submit" id="submit-form" placeholder="Submit"/>
            </form>
        </div>
        </div>
     );
  }
export default Form;
```

Comment: Have tried it already

Comment: try using `event.preventDefault()` in the first line of the function without any condition and use `required` in the input tag to stop the form from submitting before all fields are filled

Comment: Did it, it merely prevents page refreshing but doesnt execute rest of the lines that follow where the backend call is made

Comment: i have edited my code and posted your data using `FormData`

Comment: Is it printing "Working" in console on running?